# Unity - Decrease/Increase the "Z axis" angle axis on Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, euler-angles

***[See my answer below! Thanks for the comments]***

What is the best way to Decrease/Increase an angle without using "eulerAngles"?

I need turn my transform between 30 and 325, according to my "Y axis".

If it is less than zero we reduce the value of "Z axis" is greater if we increase the value of "Z axis".

[image]

I already tried:

```
if ( airPlanePlayerRigidbody2D.velocity.y < 0 ) {
         var rotationVector = airPlanePlayerTransform.rotation;
         rotationVector.z -= 2f;
         Vector3 vec = new Vector3(rotationVector.x,rotationVector.y,rotationVector.z);
         airPlanePlayerTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(vec);
 }
```

And:

```
public void Rotate(float angle)
{
    airPlanePlayerTransform.Rotate(0, 0, angle); // this rotate forever
}
```

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

In fact I already have a code that does what I need, but it is too long. I'm looking for some simpler. The result I want is this:

**A more smoothed animation:**[Smooth animation down](https://i.imgur.com/p5CWsGd.gif)

**And what I can do so far with the comments posted here, is this:**[Without animation](https://i.imgur.com/CDPAS5X.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching the topic, I managed to get the result. Thanks for the replies.

```
if (airPlanePlayerRigidbody2D.velocity.y < 0) { //falling
       var myNewQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0, 0, -30));
       var myQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z));
       transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (myQuaternion , myNewQuaternion ,  speed );
}
else if (airPlanePlayerRigidbody2D.velocity.y > 0) { // rising
       var myNewQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0, 0, 30));
       var myQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z));
       transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (myQuaternion , myNewQuaternion ,  speed );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think eulerAngeles is a good way to go with, and I successfully did the similar rotation effect in Unity by using eulerAngeles. You probably didn't find the correct way when you used it.

I used something like that:

```
Vector3 newRotationAngles = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {

        newRotationAngles.z += 1;

    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {

        newRotationAngles.z -= 1;
    }

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (newRotationAngles);
```

Output: when you press the left/right arrow keys, the gameObject will rotate, but it is not always rotating. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This seems useful, I will try to implement the necessary limitation. See, I updated the post with the results. Thank's for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
public float maxAngle = 325f; // Max Angle for Z Axis
public float minAngle = 30f; // Min Angle for Z Axis
public float rotationDelta = 1f; // you can control your rotation speed using this
float tempAngle;
void Update() 
{
    // If AirPlane is rising, velocity in y is greater than 0
    if(rigidbody2D.velocity.y > 0)
    {
        tempAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.eulerAngles.z, maxAngle, Time.time * rotationDelta);
    }
    // If AirPlane is falling, velocity in y is less than 0
    else if(rigidbody2D.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        tempAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.eulerAngles.z, minAngle, Time.time * rotationDelta);
    }
    // If AirPlane is going straight in horizontal.
    else
    {
        tempAngle = 0;
    }
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, tempAngle);
}
```

Comment: It works! But he is still very "hard", I need a smoother animation. See, I updated the post with the results. Thank's for your time.